# Several recent questions about one product

Tags: discussion

There seem to be several recent questions all asking about the Case-Shiller index, some of which seem to have been migrated from another StackExchange site. Is this getting into 
some rather advanced topics in investing that are not actively encouraged on this site?
Should some of them be closed?

Answer (score 2):

If the answers are accurate, they seem right on topic.  Understanding those kinds of indicators will be perfectly relevant to decisions people can make about personal finance.

Should they invest one way?  Should they purchase a home?  What about a second house?  Being able to read a market with a report like the Case-Shiller is good to me.

We *want* more experts on the site, and good, thoughtful discussion about advanced topics would be good content to attract them.

Comment: +1 "We want more experts on the site, and good, thoughtful discussion about advanced topics would be good content to attract them."  Couldn't agree more!